# populate date time picker from number of days

Tags: vb.net, date, datetimepicker

Am working in windows application.i am scanning my date barcode

i have a date barcode ..while scanning that barcode i am getting value to my textbox like this :

**17197...so this value means 2017 july 16,

in that 17-year

197 -calculation of days from 2017 to july 16..**

while reading this barcode i want to just populate correct date to datetime picker

how i can convert this value to date time picker..

any help is very appriciable..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the first two numbers represent the year after 2000 and the following numbers represent the days from the first of january (included) of such year then

```
Dim test = "17197"
Dim year = Convert.ToInt32(test.Substring(0,2)) + 2000
Dim days = Convert.ToInt32(test.Substring(2))
Dim currentDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(days-1)
Console.WriteLine(currentDate)  ' 16/07/2017
```

Comment: its working fine sir,,i will do 1 more round rest and let u know